# Send email in VB.Net with tls enabled server

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, tls1.2, windows-server-2003

I am developing application for sending an email with TLS enabled SMTP server and this application I want to run on windows server 2003. When I run this same application on window server 2012 R2 its working perfect but it wont work on window server 2003. Is there any specific reason it wont work on window server 2003?

> Error: SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated.

I used below code in my application:

```vb
Public Sub sendemail()
    Dim SMTPMailServer As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("xyz") 'tls enabled SMTP Server Name 
    Dim myMail As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("FromEmail", "ToEmail")
    With myMail
        .Subject = "Test Email with TLS enabled server"
        .Body = "Test Body"
        .Priority = Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal
        .IsBodyHtml = True
    End With
    SMTPMailServer.Send(myMail)
    myMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please see [Does Windows 2003 support TLS 1.1 and 1.2?](https://serverfault.com/q/793280/109573) (TL;DR: no, not natively).

Comment: @ Andrew Thanks for your response,there is any another way to run this application on windows server 2003?

Comment: Windows Server 2003 extended support ended on 14 July 2015, so it may not be possible to obtain any third-party software to enable TLS 1.2.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [How to enable TLS 1.2 protocol on windows 2003?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791513/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-protocol-on-windows-2003)

Comment: @AndrewMorton No I can't install any third party application/software on client machine because of some security issues,I am looking for any code change that make run my application on windows server 2003.

Comment: Have you enabled the less secure apps on your account ?

Comment: @Bapmop Thanks,Can you please tell me that how I do this.

Comment: What kind of Email are you using anyway ? if it is Gmail [Try This](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

Comment: @Bapmop I am using Vendors tls enabled SMTP Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New _
        Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
            SmtpServer.Port = 587
            SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress("YOURusername@gmail.com")
            mail.To.Add("TOADDRESS")
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
            mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL"
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            MsgBox("mail send")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your Response,But I tried this code also but it wont work,I am getting same error and moreover I don't want to use SMTP server as google I want to use my vendors SMTP server which by default tls enabled.